# What MCU actors have also portrayed other non-MCU Marvel characters?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe

Chris Evans portrayed the MCU Captain America and the non-MCU Human Torch.
Jon Favreau portrayed the MCU Happy Hogan and the non-MCU Foggy Nelson.

Are there any other MCU actors who've portrayed Marvel characters different from their MCU characters? I'm including the extended MCU (MTVU?) in this.

Stan Lee's cameos don't count. Also, I'm not asking about characters portrayed by multiple actors (*cough* Spider-Man *cough*).

Comment: FYI: there's no special name for the TV or Netflix parts of the MCU, they're all (nominally) just part of the MCU.

Comment: @KutuluMike Thanks! I hesitated to call it the "Extended MCU" but couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: The Netflix MCU is easily defined as the The Defenders.

Comment: I wish the question was about MCU actors who have also portrayed non-Marvel comic characters so that I answer it with *Karl Urban*, *Michael Keaton*, and *Michelle Pfiffer*. :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Photos and information are sourced from [**here**](https://web.archive.org/web/20151003143837/https://www.phactual.com/9-actors-who-played-multiple-roles-in-marvel-movies/).

### Actors who portrayed MCU and non-MCU, Marvel Universe characters:

**Ray Stevenson**

"Volstagg" from the *Thor* films (MCU) vs. "Frank Castle" from *The Punisher: War Zone*

[image: Volstagg and Frank Castle]

**Colm Feore**

"Laufey" from *Thor* (MCU) vs. "Donald Mencken" from *The Amazing Spiderman 2*

[image: Laufey][image: Mencken]

**Kate Mara**

"Unnamed US Marshall" from *Iron Man 2* (MCU) vs. "Sue Storm" *Fantastic Four* (2016)

[image: https://www.phactual.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kate-mara-iron-man-2-fantastic-four.jpg]

**Tim Blake Nelson**

"Samuel Sterns" from *The Incredible Hulk* (MCU) vs. "Harvey Elder" from *Fantastic Four* (2016)

[image]

---

### Actors who portrayed MCU and non-Marvel Universe, Marvel-published characters:

**Vincent D’Onofrio**

"Wilson Fisk / Kingpin" from *Daredevil* (MCU via Netflix) vs. "Edgar the meatsack" from *Men In Black* (reversed in image)

[image]

---

### Actors who portrayed multiple non-MCU Marvel Comics published characters:

**Nicolas Cage**

"Johnny Blaze" from the *Ghost Rider* films vs. "Big Daddy" from *Kickass*

[image]

**Peter Dinklage**

"Bolivar Trask" from the *X-Men - Days of Future Past* vs. "Eitri the Dwarf King" from *Infinity Wars*
[image]
[image]

**Rebecca Romijn**

"Mystique" from the *X-Men* films vs. "Joan" from *The Punisher* (2004)

[image]

**Ryan Reynolds**

"Hannibal King" from *Blade: Trinity* vs. both versions of "Deadpool" from *Deadpool* and *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*

[image]

Comment: Ryan Reynolds, Rebecca Romijn and Nicolas Cage have nothing to do with MCU

Comment: "Men in Black" was published by Marvel subsidiary but  was not a Marvel comic; however, D'onofrio did portray "Thor" in "Adventures in Babysitting" if we are "going there".  Likewise, "Kickass" was a Marvel publication, but it does not take place in the Marvel Universe (though it is considered an alternate dimension if it shares the same Earth as Mark Millar's "Marvel 1985" mini-series, which did crossover into the Marvel 616 universe).

Comment: I'm personally very excited about Disney's acquisition of Fox movie rights to X-Men, Fantastic Four and Deadpool.  They will be retroactively folded into the MCU, I suppose

Comment: You have Peter Dinklage listed under actors who played multiple non-MCU characters, but Infinity War is MCU.

Answer (score 13):

Since Marvel Studios' formation, character rights have been a tricky aspect of negotiation. In fact, [according to recently published studies](https://www.bloomsbury.com/uk/marvel-studios-phenomenon-9781501311895/), IP management, lease and loan has for a long time been an active part of Marvel's brand identity; despite claims to the contrary, it was not solely due to bankruptcy that Marvel pursued a strategy of franchising their characters out to other interests.

Whilst there will be multiple incarnations of characters, actors are typically locked in to studio deals meaning once they are on the MCU roster, it's unlikely they'll appear in a non-MCU marvel property. This is an implicit element of control Marvel possess over their competition, and typically means any non-MCU appearances by MCU actors are almost *always before* an MCU appearance.

You've mentioned Chris Evans already, but also:

**IDRIS ELBA**

[image]

The actor portrayed the character Moreau in *Ghost Rider: Spirit of Vengeance* (non-MCU) before Heimdall in *Thor* (MCU).

Comment: This is a much better answer to a question that probably doesn't deserve it. ;-)

Comment: "*once they are on the MCU roster, it's unlikely they'll appear in a non-MCU marvel property. This is an implicit element of control Marvel possess over their competition, and typically means any non-MCU appearances by MCU actors are almost always before an MCU appearance.*" [This isn't true in multiple cases.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/120107/1006)

Answer (score 4):

**Tony Curran** played Priest in *Blade II* (2002), Man in Black Agent in *X-Men: First Class* (2011), Bor Burison in *Thor: The Dark World* (2013 MCU film), and Finn Cooley in *Marvel's Daredevil* (2015 MCU TV series) S02E04 "Penny and Dime".

**Leonor Varela** played Nyssa in *Blade II* (2002) and Camilla Reyes in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* (2013) S01E02 "0-8-4".

**Bruce Campbell** played different cameo roles in Sam Raimi’s *Spider-Man* trilogy: Ring Announcer in *Spider-Man* (2002), Snooty Usher in *Spider-Man 2* (2004), and Maître d’ in *Spider-Man 3* (2007). He also voiced the Tutorial Guide in the video games based on the same films, as well as the Xtreme Reporter in *The Amazing Spider-Man* (2012 video game). He played Pizza Poppa in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), an MCU film also directed by Sam Raimi.

**Jon Favreau** played Franklin "Foggy" Nelson in *Daredevil* (2003) and then Happy Hogan in *Iron Man* (2008 MCU film) and reprised the role in subsequent MCU films featuring the character.

**Patton Oswalt** played Hedges in *Blade: Trinity* (2004), the five Koenig brothers in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* (2013), as well as Pip the Troll in *Eternals* (2021 MCU film). He also voiced M.O.D.O.K. in *Marvel's M.O.D.O.K.* (2021 stop-motion animated TV series).

**Ryan Reynolds** played Hannibal King in *Blade: Trinity* (2004), Wade Wilson / Deadpool in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* (2009), *Deadpool* (2016) and *Deadpool 2* (2018). He will reprise the role of Deadpool in *[Deadpool & Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_3)* (2024), which is an MCU film.

**Laurence Fishburne** voiced the Silver Surfer in *Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer* (2007), played Bill Foster in *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018 MCU film), and voiced [the Beyonder in *Marvel's Moon Girl and Devil Dinosaur*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXkEZU8TqDE) (2023).

**Tim Blake Nelson** played Samuel Sterns in *The Incredible Hulk* (2008 MCU film) and Dr. Harvey Allen in *Fantastic Four* (2015). He will reprise his role as Samuel Sterns / the Leader in *Captain America: Brave New World* (2025 MCU film).

**Clancy Brown** voiced Mr. Sinister in *Wolverine and the X-Men: Foresight* (2009), voiced Taskmaster in *Iron Man & Captain America: Heroes United* (2014), played Ray Schoonover / "the Blacksmith" in *Marvel's Daredevil* (2015 MCU TV series), and voiced Surtur in *Thor: Ragnarok* (2017).

**Djimon Hounsou** voiced Black Panther in *Black Panther* (2010 animated TV series) AKA *Black Panther: Who is the Black Panther?* He then played Korath in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014) and *Captain Marvel* (2019), which are MCU films.

**Olivia Munn** played Chess Roberts in *Iron Man 2* (2010 MCU film) and Betsy Braddock / Psylocke in *X-Men: Apocalypse* (2016).

**Idris Elba** first played Heimdall in *Thor* (2011) and reprised this role in subsequent MCU films featuring the character. He also played Moreau in *Ghost Rider: Spirit of Vengeance* (2011).

**Colm Feore** played Laufey in *Thor* (2011 MCU film) and Donald Menken in *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* (2014).

**Hiroyuki Sanada** played Shingen Yashida in *The Wolverine* (2013) and Akihiko (Yakuza boss executed by Hawkeye) in *Avengers: Endgame* (2019 MCU film). Archive footage of Hiroyuki Sanada from *Avengers: Endgame* was used in *Hawkeye* (2021) S01E01 "Never Meet Your Heroes".

**Elena Satine** played Lorelei in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* (2013 MCU TV series) and then Sonya Simonson / Dreamer in *The Gifted* (2017).

**Aaron Taylor-Johnson** played Pietro Maximoff / Quicksilver in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* (2014) and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (2015), which are MCU films. He will play Sergei Kravinoff / Kraven the Hunter in *Kraven the Hunter* (2023 Sony's Spider-Man Universe film).

**Evan Peters** played Peter Maximoff / Quicksilver in *X-Men: Days of Future Past* (2014), *X-Men: Apocalypse* (2016), *Deadpool 2* (2018), and *Dark Phoenix* (2019). He also played Ralph Bohner / "Pietro Maximoff" in *WandaVision* (2021), an MCU TV series.

**Josh Brolin** played Thanos in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014 MCU film) and reprised his role in subsequent MCU works featuring the character. He also played Nathan Summers / Cable in *Deadpool 2* (2018 Fox X-Men universe film).

**Michael B. Jordan** played Johnny Storm / Human Torch in *Fantastic Four* (2015), and then played Erik Stevens / N'Jadaka / Killlmonger in *Black Panther* (2018 MCU film).

**Donald Glover** voiced Miles Morales / Spider-Man in Season 3 of the *Ultimate Spider-Man* animated TV series. He played Aaron Davis / Prowler in *Spider-Man: Homecoming* (2017 MCU film). He had a cameo appearance as a variant of Prowler in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Hayley Lovitt** played a young Janet van Dyne / The Wasp in *Ant-Man* (2015) and *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018), which are both MCU films. She also played Sage in *The Gifted* (2017).

**Karan Soni** played Dopinder in *Deadpool* (2016) and *Deadpool 2* (2018) which are both Fox X-Men universe films. He voiced Pavitr Prabhakar / Spider-Man India in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023). He will reprise the role of Dopinder in *[Deadpool & Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_3)* (2024), which is an MCU film.

<sup>Source: [*Karan Soni and Leslie Uggams Returning for 'Deadpool 3'*. Collider](https://collider.com/deadpool-3-cast-karan-soni-leslie-uggams/)</sup>

**Oscar Isaac** played Apocalypse in *X-Men: Apocalypse* (2016 Fox X-Men universe film), Marc Spector / Steven Grant / Jake Lockley / Moon Knight in *Moon Knight* (2022 MCU TV series), and voiced Miguel O'Hara / Spider-Man 2099 in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Mahershala Ali** played Cornell Stokes / Cottonmouth in *Marvel's Luke Cage* (2016 MCU TV series) on Netflix. He voiced Aaron Davis / Prowler in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018). He made a voice cameo as Blade in *Eternals* (2021 MCU film). He is set to play Blade in a 2025 *Blade* film.

**Aubrey Plaza** played Lenny Busker in *Legion* (2017 TV series), and will play a to-be-confirmed character in *Agatha: Coven of Chaos* (an MCU TV series to be released in 2023 or 2024).

<sup>Source: [*‘WandaVision’ Spinoff ‘Agatha: Coven of Chaos’ Casts Aubrey Plaza*. Variety](https://variety.com/2022/tv/news/wandavision-spinoff-agatha-coven-of-chaos-aubrey-plaza-1235416041/)</sup>

**Daniel Kaluuya** played W'Kabi in *Black Panther* (2018 MCU film) and voiced Hobart "Hobie" Brown / Spider-Punk in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Kathryn Hahn** voiced Olivia Octavius / Doctor Octopus in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) and then played Agatha Harkness / Agnes in *WandaVision* (2021 MCU TV series). She will reprise her role as Agatha Harkness in the upcoming MCU TV series, *Agatha: Coven of Chaos* (an MCU TV series to be released in 2023 or 2024).

**Hailee Steinfeld** voiced Gwen Stacy / Spider-Woman / Spider-Gwen in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) and then played Kate Bishop in *Hawkeye* (2021 MCU TV series). She reprised her role as Gwen Stacy / Spider-Woman in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

**Brian Tyree Henry** voiced Jefferson Davis in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018) and reprised his role in subsequent Spider-Verse films featuring the character. He portrayed Phastos / Phil Stoss in *The Eternals* (2021), an MCU film.

**Lake Bell** voiced Vanessa Fisk in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018), Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow in Season 1 of *What If...?* (2021 MCU TV series), and then played Dr. Graham in *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever* (2022 MCU film).

**Russell Crowe** played Zeus in *Thor: Love and Thunder* (2022 MCU film), and will play the father of  Sergei Kravinoff / Kraven the Hunter in *Kraven the Hunter* (2024 Sony's Spider-Man Universe film).

Note: To keep the list short, I am only including actors who have played live-action Marvel characters. This excludes voice actors who have voiced multiple Marvel characters but have not played any in live-action.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of *Spider-Man: Far From Home* (2019), we now have an actor who has played a character in the MCU, and played *that same character* in a non-MCU movie: J.K. Simmons as J. Jonah Jameson.

While it takes on a different form than all of the other listed examples, J.K. Simmons still counts as an actor who was both in an MCU movie and a non-MCU Marvel movie.